# How to map the CURL command to Unit testing in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, testing, curl, functional-testing

I ran the below curl command in terminal

```
curl -d "message" http://localhost:8080/api/validate -u username:password
```

and is running as expected.

I am writing a functional test for the above in Rails. For doing this I have to call the `post` method and pass the arguments whatever I have done for `curl` to `post`.

```
post 'validate',:request => "message"
```

I am able to pass the request paramater successfully. But how do I pass the username and password that I am passing in Curl to the post method in rails. Please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The option you are passing to `curl` is setting up HTTP Basic Auth, so you need to do that in your test.

Take a look at whats going on in the answer to this question:

[Testing HTTP Basic Auth in Rails 2.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165478/testing-http-basic-auth-in-rails-2-2)