# Skip Rails http_basic_authenticate_with in RSpec test

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, controller, basic-authentication

I'm working on a MVP (minimum viable product). In order to offer a simpler way to secure the admin pages, I just did add http_basic_authenticate_with to my AdminController.

Problem is that when I want to test my AdminController, I get "unauthorized" (401) for not being logged in.

In this scenario, it's irrelevant to test the authentication - it's just temporary, and as soon I go to the next sprint, it's going to removed -, so I'm trying to skip it within RSpec.

Problem is I tried many ways, and none seems to be working.

For example, I tried to modify the http_basic_authenticate_with in order to avoid the authentication. Like this:

```
require 'spec_helper'

module ActionController
  module HttpAuthentication
    module Basic
      def http_basic_authenticate_with(*args)
      end
    end
  end
end


describe Admin::SubscribersController do  
  describe "GET 'index'" do
    it "should be OK" do 
      get 'index'
      response.should be_successful
    end
  end
end
```

But when I run it, it still returns "false" for that simple test.

Btw, in order to simplify this test, I just have an empty index action on my AdminController and an empty view (index.html.erb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Finally I got it working.

Something as stated in the docs didn't work for me:

```
get 'index', nil, 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials("admin", "password")
```

So I tried an "old" approach to do it, which is to set **request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION']** :

```
request.env['HTTP_AUTHORIZATION'] = ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials("admin","password")
```

None of the other solutions worked, so I will just keep in the meanwhile with this one.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

If it is ok to skip authentication for *all tests* for a controller, here's the technique I'm using on a current project.

```
unless Rails.env.test?
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "slothbear", password: "kuniklo"
end
```

Comment: Hm, now that I've typed that out loud, I think I'd change the condition to `if Rails.env.production?` I really don't need authentication in the development environment either. Thanks for leading me to greater productivity.

Comment: And here's a good recommendation for not using `production?` as the test: http://stackoverflow.com/q/8741398/2464

Answer (score 2):

In Rails 5.x, this works:

```
allow(subject).to receive(:authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic)
  .with(anything).and_return true
```

In Rails 6.x, this works:

```
allow(subject).to receive(:http_basic_authenticate_or_request_with)
  .with(anything).and_return true
```

This is because `http_basic_authenticate_with` is a class-level method that adds a `before_action` that actually calls one of these two methods under the hood.

You can see which one to use by checking out `http_authentication.rb` [here for Rails 6](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v6.0.0.rc1/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L72-L74) or [here for Rails 5](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v5.2.3/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L71-L79)

Answer (score 0):

You can or even should test authentication. Write test for unauthenticated (it is now) and authenticated.
See [Testing HTTP Basic Auth in Rails 2.2+](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1165478/testing-http-basic-auth-in-rails-2-2) it should help.

Comment: Thanks, but in my case (as I said it's just temporary, and probably next week it's going to be removed already) I want to avoid it. Is it possible? Any suggestions on how to skip it?

Comment: So maybe you dont need tests at all? But you can do some metaprogramming to avoid it or, which is fastest option - use method in link I found...

Comment: I'm sorry, I guess I did express myself a little wrong. The example I gave above was just an example. My real AdminController isn't going to be just that - however, HTTP authentication is temporary. I didn't want to authenticate before my tests because that means when I change the password, I will have to change test too. Thought skip it would be easier and a better approach. If you have an example on how I could skip (the example I gave was the only idea I had), please let me know.

Comment: As I said, you need to investigate here: https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/9959233e24eedec4b39e53b6ea0261420ac41f63/actionpack/lib/action_controller/metal/http_authentication.rb#L111, maybe skip_before_filter can help? Or store password in top level constant to avoid changing it in specs.

Comment: And on your example above it should be:

self << Admin::SubscribersController;
  def http_basic_authenticate_with(*);
  end;
end

Comment: I tried a before(:each) hook, containing:  controller.class.skip_before_filter :http_basic_authenticate_with. No luck. So I did try to add: 'HTTP_AUTHORIZATION' => ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic.encode_credentials("root", "root") as my 3rd parameter on the HTTP request. Still no luck. Both cases give me a response.status of 401, which means both are not bypassing/authenticating. I did not understand your last example. Shouldn't it be something as "class << self"? Thanks for all the support.

Comment: ups, I mean  class << Admin::SubscribersController; def http_basic_authenticate_with(*); end; end