# Rails 3 http_basic_authenticate_with only in production environment?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, basic-authentication

is there a way to only use

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => 'user', :password => 'secret'
```

when the server is running on production mode?

Answer (score 34):

Yes, try:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_filter :authenticate

  def authenticate
    if Rails.env.production?
      authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
        username == "user" && password == "%$§$§"
      end 
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you too for the quick reply!

Comment: I'm not a fan of `Rails.env.production?` because it ends up true no matter which server the app is running on. I prefer using putting the username/password in environment variables and deciding to authenticate based on whether those are set. But I realize that's out of the scope of this question. :)

Answer (score 16):

Just add this to your example

```
http_basic_authenticate_with :name => 'user', :password => 'secret' if Rails.env.production?
```

Answer (score 6):

```
authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password|
  username == "user" && password == "secret"
end if Rails.env.production?
```