# rails 4 multisite http_basic_authenticate_with

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, authentication, heroku, basic-authentication

have been trying to solve this for 6 hours now. Hope someone can nail this. I have one codebase running multiple apps on heroku. Some apps already have their own domain. I am already using the host to set locale for each app which is working fine. See below. But authenticating (hide non-ready apps from public) per host doesn't work.

Setting the locale in application controller - working nicely:

```
before_filter :extract_locale_from_domain

def extract_locale_from_domain
 domain = request.host
 if domain == 'www.domain.hu'
  I18n.locale = :'hu'
 elsif domain == 'www.domain.com'
  I18n.locale = :'en-US'
 else
  I18n.locale = :'en-US'
 end
end
```

Now my home page is 'static_pages#home' so first I thought I put the method in the static_pages_controller but that didn't work so I even tried in the application_controller. Even tried to set default URLs per environment (in application_controller) but no luck with that neither ([more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8741398/rails-3-http-basic-authenticate-with-only-in-production-environment)). Oh yes, and I tried to restrict per environment with no luck. So I tried several versions this is the one in application_controller (giving nomethod error):

```
before_filter :authenticate

def authenticate
 domain = request.host
 if domain == 'www.domain.hu'
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "stuff", password: "boda"
 elsif domain == 'www.domain.com'
  http_basic_authenticate_with name: "stuff", password: "boda"
 else
 end
end
```

This gives the error:

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `http_basic_authenticate_with' for #    
< StaticPagesController:0x000000090d8de8 >):
app/controllers/application_controller.rb:49:in `authenticate'
```

TIA!

Answer (score 1):

This is what worked:

In applicaiton controller:

```
before_filter :authenticate

....

protected

def authenticate
 domain = request.host
 if domain == 'www.domain.hu' 
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password| username == 'stuff' && password == 'boda'
  end
 elsif domain == 'www.domain.com'
  authenticate_or_request_with_http_basic do |username, password| username == 'stuff' && password == 'boda'
 end
end
end
```

Comment: So my answer above did not help or work? Let me know. If not, I will delete the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
NoMethodError (undefined method `http_basic_authenticate_with' for #    
< StaticPagesController:0x000000090d8de8 >)
```

This means it can't find the `http_basic_authenticate_with` method on the `StaticPagesController` instance.

Try including [ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic.html) and [ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/HttpAuthentication/Basic/ControllerMethods.html) modules in your controller and then try to use the `http_basic_authenticate_with` method again.

Comment: Hi Rakibul! 
Thx for the quick reply. Added the includes but still get the nomethod error. Now the controller starts like this: class StaticPagesController < ApplicationController
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic
  include ActionController::HttpAuthentication::Basic::ControllerMethods

Comment: I suspect your if else logic is not working correctly. Try without any if else for testing first. Just have this: `http_basic_authenticate_with name: "stuff", password: "boda"` and go to the url and see if that works. It should work.

Comment: awesome, now you just need to debug and make your if else logic work properly. do a `puts domain.inspect` and see what value you get for `domain`. Then, based on that build your if else conditions.

Comment: you mean in console?
>> puts domain.inspect
NameError: undefined local variable or method `domain' for main:Object

Comment: not in console, in your controller. just print the value so that you can see what you get for domain when you make the request.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96081/discussion-between-zsolt-and-k-m-rakibul-islam).